# How to achieve the layering effect of one Composable on top of another when showing a dialog using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-animation, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog, layouttransition

I'm hoping to understand how I can achieve this behavior using Jetpack Compose in Android when displaying a dialog on top of the current Composable view.

Desired State:

[image]

Animation when clicking on the Filter button at the bottom. This is from the app Culture Trip on iOS.

[image]

I currently have a dialog like below. If you notice, my content is still visible but I would like to have it appear as if it's a page layer that's in the background.

Notice the red arrow in the desired state picture. I can mimic that behavior by having a row and setting the background color with padding but looking for a more elegant solution or wondering if there is standard behavior that I don't know about.

Actual State:

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Do you mean you want your dialog to be above the content? That's default for dialogs. Dialog on your screen seems to be standard `BottomSheetModal`

Comment: @Jakoss I updated my original post. Let me know if that clarifies the question

Answer (score 0):

For displaying your dialog above, you need to use Box and call dialog at the very bottom of this Box.